# PWA version of site slow and sometimes reloads on each activation

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

This is an intermittent behavior with the progressive web app version of my site.

I made a [website](https://www.stopindoctrination.org) with React. Then I visited it with my iPhone 5 and saved it to my Home screen with Safari's "Add to Home Screen" feature. The behavior is different between (1) visiting the site using the home screen shortcut and (2) opening Safari and going to the page that way.

Doing (1) has the problem. If I do that and then go to the Home screen and touch the shortcut and go back to the website, the page turns all white for about 1-5 seconds, the internet connecting indicator spins and the page appears. Sometimes the page returns to the state I left it and sometimes it reloads entirely. Doing (2), the page doesn't reload at all and doesn't try to access the internet. Same with accessing the site using Chrome.

It seems to completely reload more often if more time has passed since I .

According to Chrome developer tools, a Service Worker is activated and Lighthouse gives the site a perfect PWA score.

I have questions... Why is the behavior different when accessing the page these two ways? Why is it trying to access the internet or doing anything at all every time I switch from the Home screen or another app to this app? Why is it totally reloading the page sometimes? How do I make it not do this? I want it to work offline and I want it to not attempt connect to the internet unnecessarily.

Comment: Could you test on android in order to validate if is a ios rare behavior? Could you put a console.log or alert very early in your app in order to validate if is a renderization lag?

Comment: I'm really not sure what's going on. I tested it on Android and it was okay. Then I added an alert at the beginning of the ComponentDidMount of my app's containing page. I deployed and previewed that on netlify, and added it to my home screen as a pwa next to the original. It alerted once. It reloaded once. Then it and the original both behaved much better and it didn't alert even after restarting the pwa. It did alert the first time after restarting the phone. Also since restarting the delay seems to be about 1-2 seconds instead of 5-6 seconds but that's still more than 0 seconds w Safari.

Comment: Disregard the part about it working faster. It's slow again.